# Model a Sports Player and query it with spring data JPA

Tags: java, oop, database-design, spring-data-jpa

I have a data **model** in Spring Boot with Spring Data JPA called **Player**. This represents a person in sports and this player has a property called jerseyNumber (a number) and position (where he plays, center, defense etc..). These properties have different values as his career progresses. One season he plays as number 8 and other as number 7.

```
Player name 1
jerseyNumber 8 - Position center - 01.01.2020-31.12.2020
jerseyNumber 7 - Position attacker - 01.01.2021-Present
```

**How do i set-up spring data JPA to handle a query where i want to know the exact state at a specific date? Lets say i want to know the details of the model on 01.06.2020.**

I am using *Postgres*.

Here is what I was thinking would be an option.
I'm ommiting the service code that pulls the player from a repository and calculates the current state. Basically going through each of the fields and determines the current state based on a provided timestamp and returns a separate DTO model from it. Is this a good approach?
I'm a bit concerned that these are join queries which I would mostly need to do eagerly. I'm considering maybe storing this data in a *JSONB* column within the player table. My API needs to serve potentially a hundred players in a single response. This example is a bit simplified as this pattern exists around different entities in the application as well (querying which teams had which players at a specific point in time etc..)

```
@Entity
public class Player {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "player")
    private List<PlayerNumber> playerNumbers = new ArrayList<>();

    // Getters and setters
}
```

```
@Entity
public class PlayerNumber {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private int number;
    private LocalDate startDate;
    private LocalDate endDate;

    @ManyToOne
    private Player player;

    // Getters and setters
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say your data models are a good approach, but the idea of fetching players at a specific point in time by using service or eager load is not.
We go to each of your concerns.

1. SQL query to fetch players at a specific point in time.

```
select *
from player_number pn
join player p on pn.player_id = p.id
where pn.start_date < :date
and (pn.end_date > :date or pn.end_date is null) // Suspect null is present
```

2. Using `spring-data-jpa`
   There are several ways to implement this, refer to this [doc](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-query) example

```
public interface PlayerNumberRepository extends JpaRepository<PlayerNumber, Long> {

    @Query("SELECT p FROM PlayNumber p WHERE p.startTime <= ?1 and (p.endTime >= ?1 or p.endTime is null)")
    List<FuelPrice> findInSpecificPointInTime(LocalDate pointInTime);
}
```

3. You want to have results with multiple joins, you can use
   `Proxy projection` aka custom dto and also can apply pagination. Example

```
public interface PlayerDto {
    Long getId();
    int getNumber();
    // All getters properties
}
```

And apply it to repository

```
public interface PlayerNumberRepository extends JpaRepository<PlayerNumber, Long> {

    @Query(nativeQuery = true,
value="select p.id as id, pn.number as number
from player_number pn
join player p on pn.player_id = p.id
where pn.start_date < :date
and (pn.end_date > :date or pn.end_date is null)")
    List<PlayerDto> findInSpecificPointInTime(LocalDate pointInTime);
}
```

This is [example](https://vladmihalcea.com/spring-jpa-dto-projection/), I hope it helps.